# if then else loop problem delphi

Tags: delphi, loops, if-statement

I'm still a beginner and I have been trying to solve this problem by my self but I guess I 'm out of luck. I think it is probably quite simple but here's the deal.

I have 3 checkboxes. Each one writes a specific line in a text file when a button is pressed but if none are selected. I want a message to be displayed. But what happens there is that the message pops out even if one checkbox is checked. Here's the code: (btw, feel free to suggest any other code that would make it easier/clearer)

```
if cbSCV.Checked then
  WriteLn(permFile, 'scv');
if cbMP.Checked then
  WriteLn(permFile, 'mp');
if cbBTK.Checked then 
  WriteLn(permFile, 'btk'); 
if not (cbBTK.Checked) and not (cbMP.Checked) and not (cbBTK.Checked) then
  showmessage('Choose at least 1 option.');
```

Comment: Just rename the `if sentence` to  `if not (cbBTK.Checked) and not (cbMP.Checked) and not (cbSCV.Checked) then
` because you are cheking the `cbBTK.checked` value twice.

Comment: yeah actually if you look at the code, that's exactly what I did....

Comment: @RRUZ: You should post your comment as an answer, as it solves the problem. @Gab: When he does, you should accept it. :)

Comment: omg i'm so sorry. Thank you anyway maybe I need some sleep... Good thing there is that my code was Ok.

Comment: Yeah otherwise i'll delete this question out of shame XD

Comment: @Gab, we all have these moments. Don't be ashamed, but try to learn from it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try replacing the `if sentence` to

```
if not (cbBTK.Checked) and not (cbMP.Checked) and not (cbSCV.Checked) then
```

because you are checking the `cbBTK.checked` value twice

Comment: Why bother with the parens? What's wrong with: `if not cbBTK.Checked and not cbMP.Checked and not cbSCV.Checked then`

Answer (score 6):

For what it's worth I'd probably reverse the logic and write the troublesome test like this:

```
if not (cbBTK.Checked or cbMP.Checked or cbSCV.Checked) then
```

Answer (score 2):

To complement @soid's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5944360/if-then-else-loop-problem-delphi/5946966#5946966): I'd probably write it like this:

```
procedure TForm1.CheckIt;
var
  Count: Integer;

  procedure HandleCheckBox(ACheckBox: TCheckBox; const AID: string);
  begin
    if ACheckBox.Checked then
    begin
      WriteLn(permFile, AID);
      Inc(Count);
    end;
  end;

begin
  Count := 0;
  HandleCheckBox(cbSCV, 'scv');
  HandleCheckBox(cbMP, 'mp');
  HandleCheckBox(cbBTK, 'btk');
  if Count = 0 then
    ShowMessage('Choose at least 1 option.');
end;
```

This is a few more lines but it is IMHO less error prone and more "automatic" if you later need a fourth or fifth checkbox.

Comment: +1 but I don't like using `Count` like that; a var parameter to `HandleCheckBox` feels better to me; we are in to pedantry mode now though because the idea of doing the test of `Checked` just once is a big improvement.

Comment: @David: That's really a matter of taste. I think making Count a var parameter would just add needless noise. Its scope is clear enough even as a local variable.

Comment: This question is all about taste. All the solutions work. Clearly we all have very slightly different tastes!

Answer (score 1):

I would rewrite it like this:

```
if cbSCV.Checked then WriteLn(permFile, 'scv');
if cbMP .Checked then WriteLn(permFile, 'mp' );
if cbBTK.Checked then WriteLn(permFile, 'btk');

if not (cbSCV.Checked) and 
   not (cbMP .Checked) and 
   not (cbBTK.Checked)     then
  showmessage('Choose at least 1 option.');
```

This takes the same number of lines but places the repeated elements together to make it easy to read the whole construct quickly and spot places where you are not following the pattern. Your bug, which we have all had in our code, is easier to see if it is written like this.

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm. For those things I like a set-based approach.
One way is this

```
type
  TEnumSomething = (esSCV, esMP, esBTK);
  TSomethingSet = set of TEnumSomething;

{var section}
var
  Conj: TSomethingSet;
{code section}
Conj := [];
if cbSCV.checked then 
begin
  Conj := conj + [esSCV];
  WriteLn(permFile, 'scv');
end;  
{do this for the other 2 checkboxes}
If Conj = []  then ShowMessage('');
```

You can also make `Conj` an form field and make checkboxes 
set/unset this on their OnClick event.

Warning: maybe some syntax detail is missing, I'm not on delphi IDE now...

Comment: FWIW I'd prefer `Include(Conj, esSCV);` to `Conj := conj + [esSCV];`.

Comment: @Ulrich, I was trying to remember what are statement to do that on sets... "Include" was it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I probably wouldn't rewrite it like this, but hey, this is fun. I'm at work and I don't have Delphi here, so this is just sample code. Generics!

```
type
    TCheckBoxDict: TDictionary<String, TCheckBox>;
var
    Dict: TCheckBoxDict;
    function HandleCheckBoxes(ADict: TCheckBoxDict) : boolean;
    var
        Key: String;
        CheckBox: TCheckBox;
    begin
        Result := false;
        for Key in ADict.Keys do
            if ADict.Items[Key].Checked then
            begin
                WriteLn(permFile, Key);
                Result := true;
            end;
    end;
begin
    Dict := TCheckBoxDict.Create;
    Dict.Add('scv', cbSCV);
    Dict.Add('mp', cbMP);
    Dict.Add('btk', cbBTK);
    if not HandleCheckBoxes(Dict) then
        ShowMessage('Choose at least one option');
    Dict.Destroy;
end;
```

Comment: Nitpicker's corner: I guess that should be `for Key in Dict.Keys do` and `WriteLn(permFile, Key);`. And you missed the try-finally for Dict. :-)

Comment: Heh, you're right. I'm still leaving out the try-finally block for now. Thank you!